# Analyze AWS NAT cost

Tags: cost-management, aws-nat-gateway

I used the docs I found online to analyze the main contributors to the NAT gateway huge!!! cost.
So I have now a list of IPs, but I can't determine to who each one belongs.
I am using some 3rd party apps that might be related to the IPs, but I am struggling to find their possible ranges of IPs. For example (Confluent Kafka, Snowflake and more).
Any thoughts?

Comment: You could try using one of the many online IP lookup/WHOIS tools

Answer (score 0):

Unix terminal usually includes whois:

`whois 12.46.8.0`

which looks up the IP owners in a registry.
ex. the above IP belongs to AT&T

```
NetRange:       12.0.0.0 - 12.255.255.255
CIDR:           12.0.0.0/8
NetName:        ATT
...
Organization:   AT&T Services, Inc. (ATTW-Z)
```

Another great tool is GeoIP lookup by Maxmind. This gives you a location AND the registered organization.
https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo